# Commit mutation from action in another store via root? Vue2 Nuxt Vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vuex

This has been beating me up.
I have a vuex store, inside is a folder called "RyansBag" im using to test things.
I have two other folder, Alerts and Inventory. So the folder structure for each of these goes

store> Ryansbag/Alert/...

in my Inventory index.js file, we run  a function to add an item to an inventory system.

```
async addInventory_Catalog({commit}, payload){
          try{

        const response = await this.$axios.put('Inventory/AddFromCatalogDefault', null, {
            params:{
            originalUPC: payload.upc, 
            clientID: payload.clientId, 
            saleprice: payload.sellPrice,
            cost: payload.sellPrice,
            Condition: payload.condition.conditionName,
            Serial: payload.serialNumber,
            Notes: payload.notes,
            HoldDays: payload.holdDays,
          }
        });
     console.log(response.data.success)
     commit('RyansBag/Alerts/showAlerts', 'You have added a product!', {root: true})
     return response.data;
  } catch (error) { alert(error); console.log(error); }
  },
```

Here we just pass the item down, and when it's done - commit the changes to our alert which is in store > RyansBag/Alerts.

You can see I tried to call it:

```
commit('RyansBag/Alerts/showAlerts', 'You have added a product!', {root: true})
```

My understanding was to simply state the commit is coming from this store as the root state...? But Im not sure if im supposed to register the commit in /Alerts as a global item somehow. ( https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html#accessing-global-assets-in-namespaced-modules )

EDIT:::
Edit: There was no commit request in the action. added to post. Now however I get warning to not mutate state outside of state handlers..

Below is the mutation it's requesting to reach inside the alerts.

```
export const mutations = {
    showAlerts(state, message) {
        let timeout = 0
        if (state.status.showAlert) {
          state.status.showAlert = false
          timeout = 300
        }
        setTimeout(() => {
          state.status.showAlert = true
          state.status.message = message
        }, timeout)
      },

      hideAlerts(state) {
        state.status.showAlert = false
      },
}
```

Comment: Have you add a `namespaced: true` in your vuex modules?

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. It's unknown what store code exactly is

Comment: edited with store code.

Comment: my understanding is that since its nuxt.js, namespace modules is defaulted to true. I am also calling map actions etc in other places with none issue - so it must be true I think. Ive yet found where the option is with nuxt.js

Answer (score 0):

The fix was a) making sure I called commit in the action parameters. and b) not using setTimeout in the mutation, but instead setting a mutation to hide, and using the actions to setTime.